# Weird markdown rendering

Tags: support, markdown

The rendering for `**t**op` in the answer in [Two-column itemization with title in each column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99317/two-column-itemization-with-title-in-each-column) appeared as **t**op. Is this a known bug in this site?

Comment: I just found this post: [Where to report bugs about this site?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1456). So my follow-up question is a duplicate. *This* is the right place to ask. `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intra-word emphasis by Markdown is not supported, by design:

- [Three Markdown Gotchas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/) (SO blog post)
- [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words) (meta.SO)
- Similar: [Markdown handles inline bold text (within a word) incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51404/markdown-handles-inline-bold-text-within-a-word-incorrectly)